# Calling origin function in mock.patch

Tags: python, mocking

I have a function where I use shutil.move to move multiple files to another location. When it fails, I want to call some cleaning code. So I wrote an automated test, where I have five files, I want to raise an Exception on the third call of shutil.move and check if cleaning was done. My naive idea was:

```
def test_failed_processing_clean_ups_database(self):
    class LocalCounter:
        call_counter = 0

    def code_breaker(src, dst):
        LocalCounter.call_counter += 1
        if LocalCounter.call_counter > 2:
            raise CodeBreakerException('Code made booom!')
        shutil.move(src, dst)

    with mock.patch('dashboard.tasks.shutil.move') as mck:
        mck.side_effect = code_breaker
        my_processing_code_that_uses_shutil_move()
    # check if clean...
```

But this does not work. shutil.move is patched in code_breaker function too, so it gets stacked. I need to call the original shutil.move because other things depends on this. Any suggestions how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `shutil` import line in this test file?

Comment: Yes, I have. Else I would end with a NameError exception.